# Swift 4 Cannot invoke 'index' with an argument list of type

Tags: arrays, swift, swift4

I have a problem with calling the array method `index(of:)`.
`MyClass` inherits from `UIViewController` and conforms to the `MyDelegate` protocol.

```
//self.viewControllers: [(UIViewController & MyDelegate)]
guard let myController = viewController as? MyClass,
let index = self.viewControllers.index(of: myController) else {return}
```

then I get the error:

> Cannot invoke 'index' with an argument list of type '(of: (UIViewController & MyDelegate))'

How can I solve this problem and is there a better solution than implementing `index(of:)` in an extension?

```
extension Array where Element == (UIViewController & MyDelegate) { 
    func index(of: Element) -> Int? { 
        for i in 0..<self.count { 
            if self[i] == of {
                return i
            } 
        } 
        return nil 
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is almost certainly just an extension of the fact that protocols (aka. existentials) [don't conform to themselves](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43408193/2976878). So the [*class existential*](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0156-subclass-existentials.md) `UIViewController & MyDelegate` doesn't conform to `Equatable`, even though `UIViewController` does.

Therefore because `index(of:)` is constrained to being called on a `Collection` with `Equatable` elements, you cannot call it on a `[UIViewController & MyDelegate]`.

Here's a more minimal example:

```
protocol P {}
protocol X {}
class Foo : P {}

func foo<T : P>(_ t: T) {}

func bar(_ f: Foo & X) {
  // error: Protocol type 'Foo & X' cannot conform to 'P' because only concrete
  // types can conform to protocols
  foo(f)
}
```

We cannot pass `f` as an argument to `foo(_:)` as `Foo & X` doesn't conform to `P`, even though `Foo` does. However really this should be a clear-cut case of where the existential *should always* be able to conform to itself, so I went ahead and [filed a bug](https://bugs.swift.org/browse/SR-5188).

Until fixed, a simple solution is just to do an intermediate cast to the concrete type – so in our example, we can do:

```
foo(f as Foo)
```

and in your example, you can do:

```
let index = (self.viewControllers as [UIViewController]).index(of: myController)
```

Comment: I have an array of a root class with no extensions and am getting the same error when using `index(of:)`. If I make the root class inherit from NSObject, everything works fine. Any suggestion as to why that is?

Comment: @jjatie That just sounds like a case where your root class doesn't conform to `Equatable` – by inheriting from `NSObject`, you get a conformance (which is by default based on identity). What you should do is conform your class to `Equatable` – no need to inherit from `NSObject` in this case.

Comment: Silly me! Thank you.